# How to find minimum value from vector with some condition?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to get the min element value (`x`) in a vector.

Given the index `i` of `x`, I need to check if `flag[i] == 0` to return `i`.

I don't want to sort or discard any value because I need its ordinal number, I need the vector to hold its "structure".

How can I get the index of that minimum element?

```
   A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1}
flag = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}
```

`min_element = -1`, but `flag[5] = 1`, same for element `0`, so `min_element` should be `1` at index 0.

Ps: I want to shortest solution

Comment: the question is unclear. You can use a custom comparator for `std::min_element`

Comment: I just edited the example, hope it helps

Comment: the example code is incomplete and unclear. Please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. If I do understand the question you just want to find minimum in one vector where another vector is `true`/`1`. If thats the case a mre needs two vectors and a call to `std::min_element`, some example input and expected output, not much more

Comment: sorry, now hopefully easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a filter view of `A` with only the elements where `flag` is 0, and pass that to `std::ranges::min`.

With C++23 range views:

```
namespace views = std::ranges::views;
// min is undefined if passed an empty range
assert(std::ranges::any_of(flag, [](auto f){ return f == 0; });
auto value = std::ranges::min(views::zip(A, flag)
                            | views::filter([](auto && item){ return std::get<1>(item) == 0; })
                            | views::transform([](auto && item){ return std::get<0>(item); }));
```

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rcjjf5s8h)

Answer (score 2):

If you store both arrays in a single `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` you can use `std::min_element` directly:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A    = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1};
    std::vector<int> flag = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};

    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> flag_and_A;
    for (int i=0;i<A.size();++i){
        flag_and_A.push_back({flag[i],A[i]});
    }
    auto it = std::min_element(flag_and_A.begin(),flag_and_A.end());
    std::cout << it->second;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6GETeKr5M)

`std::pair::operator<` induces a lexicographical odering, ie first `first` (the flag) is compared then `second` (`A`). In other words, entries with `flag == 0` are considered smaller than entries with `flag == 1`.

If you do not want to construct the `vector<pair<int,int>>` you can still use `std::pair::operator<` (more precisely the following uses `std::tuple<int,int>::operator<` which is basically the same):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> A    = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1};
    std::vector<int> flag = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};


    auto it = std::min_element(A.begin(),A.end(),[&](const int& a,const int& b){
        unsigned index_a = &a - &A[0];
        unsigned index_b = &b - &A[0];
        return std::tie(flag[index_a],a) < std::tie(flag[index_b],b);
    });
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f6hn8675G)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a copy of the vector, to sort, record the min-element,and then clear the copy vector.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<int> A =    {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, -1};
    vector<int> flag = {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};

    size_t index = -1;
    int min_value = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i) {
        if ((flag[i] == 0) && (index == -1 || A[i] < min_value)) {
            index = i;
            min_value = A[i];
        }   
    }

    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "not found";
    }
    else {
        cout << "min is A[" << index << "]: " << A[index];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/0l3rJQ)